# Assuming $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions of $y'' +p(x)y' +q(x)y=0$, find a first order constant coefficient DE satisfied by Wronskian, and solve it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

> $$y'' +p(x)y' +q(x)y=0$$
> Assuming $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions of the given DE, find a first order constant coefficient DE satisfied by their Wronskian, and solve it.

I don't really understand how to approach this. The DE has to be constant-coefficient and first-order but how do I get it from this with just knowing that $y_1$ and $y_2$. I mean what does the second part have to do with the given equation?

Comment: Well, turn the crank: write down $W$, take its derivative, replace the second derivatives that show up by using the DE. Then add that calculation to your question and we can discuss how it simplifies to only involve $W$.

Comment: @Ian Ok, so I found the determinant of the Wronskian as $y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2$. And then I took its derivative which came out to be: $$y_1'y_2' + y_1' y_2'' - y_1''y_2-y_1'y_2'$$ Replaced the double derivatives with $y'' = -p(x)y' -q(x)y$. Now what?

Comment: Upon further pondering I found $W' =-p(x)\cdot W$. How does that help me?

Comment: you can solve it It's a first order ode. $( \ln W)'=-p(x)$ Integrate.

Comment: Well first off it helps because it was part of the question, but as for solving it, it's first order linear (also separable) so you can solve it (integrating factors or separate variables).

Comment: Thanks! Is this answer correct? $$W=C\cdot e^{-\int p(x)dx}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ian !

Comment: Yes this is correct.